How to prevent NextJS Image from stretching on its own
I have a huge issue with NextJS Image component. When I give it an image as a source, it doesn't stick to the normal dimensions but weirdly sets some enormous width and size dimensions. I don't want to set those manually through props nor do I want to use fill prop, I just want my images to work as they did with React, is there any way to make that work?

No. You have to provide the height and width for the image tag in next js. If you're using local images, you can go without height and width, but it is required in images served remotely. Here is the word from their official docs

The width and height attributes are used to infer the correct aspect
ratio of image and avoid layout shift from the image loading in. The
width and height do not determine the rendered size of the image file.

In react, most probably you might be using to make the images responsive. This images when working with react are loaded of same sizes, for all the clients(mobile, desktop).
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

However, nextjs internally optimizes the images for different devices based on their type. Although, you can use the responsive properties to make your image better in nextjs.
Responsive Image in Next Js
Image optimisation in NextJs
